# Excel Determining if the data type of a cell is DateTime or Int

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, int

I am working on some functionality, which needs to know the data types of columns of a user given Excel Spreadsheet. These spreadsheets could have various formats, there is no standard format besides the first row being the names for the columns. The problem I am having is being able to differentiate between integers and DateTime Columns. Currently, I am using the following function to determine if a cell is a DateTime cell or not:

```
 private bool isOADate(double Val)
 {
     try
     {
         DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(Val);
         return true;
     }
     catch (ArgumentException)
     {
         return false;    
     }
 }
```

However if a cell has 1, 2, 3 etc in it, this function returns true as it is able to convert these to 1899/12/31 12:00:00 AM, 1900/01/01 12:00:00 AM, 1900/01/02 12:00:00 AM respectively. Is there a better way to determine the DateTime data type of cell? Or can you suggest an improvement on my current function so as to differentiate between them?

Comment: you could test on the cell's format ! In a cell, that's what differenciates a number from a date/time after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every cell in Excel contains either a formula, a text string or a double numeric value.

A date/time is just a number, so 11:02 on 02-Jan-2013 is 41276.45972, representing the number of days since 31-Dec-1899 (incorporating the old Lotus 123 error of believing 1900 was a leap year).

So there's no way to be certain that a cell contains a date value without knowing something about the specific context of the worksheet.

If you know that dates will fall within a certain range (in particular we can often define at least a lower bound) then the function can be enhanced to test for a minimum value.

Further, if you can work with a reference to the cell itself and you know that cells containing values that represent date/times will be formatted appropriately, then you can test the `NumberFormat` property for something date/time-related (but this can quickly get complicated where custom formats are in use).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, we cannot set any limits on the date. I do think the answer might lie in the `NumberFormat`, however as you say the custom formats can prove problematic. Can you think of a problem with simply searching in within the `NumberFormat` for `'y'`, `'m'`, and `'d'` as a means of determining if the cell is DateTime?

Comment: @Shane - searching the NumberFormat property as described ought to work, I think. Of course, if you can get to the VBA `ISDate()` function as @Jüri describes (I didn't know about how this function behaves with a cell reference) then that's worth exploring too.

Comment: I have managed to get the differentiation through the number format. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

VBA function `Isdate()` checks also the cell format: `27/01/2012`gives `True`, the result of its integer equivalent `40935` is `False`.

Comment: Thank you for this. `IsDate()` seems to do what I need, however I need to use C# and I can't seem to think of an easy way to get to this function.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/dc9ba956-6370-424a-95f5-1b4539c64a66: try 9-vote answer

Answer (score -1):

Excel stores date times as integers. In absence of any other context, you cannot differentiate between an integer and a date time. Unless the user has specified a column as date time; in which case you can read the .numberformat and deduce the type of the column from that.